Instantaneous power in a solenoid, increasing current, taking into account the Lenz current
Consider a solenoid through which we pass a current going from $0$ to $I_0$. The course gives the power consumed instantaneously by the solenoid by the formula $\epsilon I$ where $\epsilon$ is the EMF due to Faraday's law and $I$ is the current at time $t>0$. Two problems. First, since the class only motivates the use of $P=\epsilon I$ by an analogy with $P=UI$ from electrostatics, I feel highly suspicious of this formula (and I will use instead $P=RI^2$ in my following argument). Second, since there is a Lenz current arising from Faraday's law, I think the current we should take into consideration for the instantaneous power is rather the sum of $I$ plus the Lenz current.
So, here's my derivation for $P$.
First, $\epsilon = RI_{\text{ind}}  = - L \dfrac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}$ (where $R$ is the resistance of the solenoid, $L$ its self-inductance and $I_{\text{ind}}$ the Lenz current) gives:
$$ I^{\text{total}}= I - \frac{L}{R} \frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}$$
Then, the Joule dissipation in the solenoid would be:
$$R(I^{\text{total}})^2 = RI^2 + \frac{L^2}{R} \left(\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 - 2LI\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt} \tag{1}$$
So, the power dissipated through the solenoid instantaneously would be given by the last formula $(1)$.
Is it possible to neglect something and arrive at something coherent with the formula given in class ($P=LI\dfrac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}$)?
I am having a tough time with this self-induction chapter.

You're going to have to define what you mean by "back current". We often talk about the back emf of a solenoid, but this is the first time I've heard the term back current. Google hasn't returned any helpful hits for this term either.

I have edited my post.

Faraday's law says that emf is induced, not current. Current may be the source of the changing magnetic flux that induces the emf. It isn't the thing that is induced in Faraday's law.

Ok, so in addition to a bad wording, is there a conceptual mistake in my question ? That there isn't an additional current (provoked by the back emf) that opposes $I(t)$ ? I have changed induced current for "Lenz" current in my post.

Both Lenz's law and the sign convention of Faraday's law basically come from conservation of energy. Faradays law says that in order to produce a magnetic field from a wire or solenoid you must deliver electrical energy from the driving circuit. Lenz's law says that when a magnetic field induces a current in a wire, it takes energy out of the magnetic field.

You are mixing up two (or maybe more) things.
You learned a formula $P=\epsilon I$. This is a formula for an ideal (resistance-free) solenoid. It accounts for electrical energy in the circuit being stored or recovered from the magnetic field in the solenoid.
In a real solenoid, there are also Joule losses due to the imperfect conductivity of the wires. These are a separate component of the power you must deliver to the solenoid to charge it magnetically (and they reduce the energy recovered when the solenoid discharges). This is not accounted for in the formula you learned in class.
Because these effects are entirely separate effects (Joule dissipation and magnetic energy storage) you can't equate them as you did in your equation $\epsilon = RI_{\text{ind}}$.
The formula you learned in class is about power used to change the energy stored in the magnetic field, not about resistive (Joule) dissipation.

"This is a formula for an ideal (resistance-free) solenoid". But then, if the solenoid is resistance-free, against what does the $\vec{E}$ in the Emf works in order to displace a charge from one end of the solenoid to the other end ? If this is effortless, then what is $\vec{E}$ working against ?

It is working against the EMF induced by the changing magnetic field in the solenoid according to Faraday's law. It isn't effortless (when |I| is increasing) because energy is needed to increase the magnetic field.

But $\epsilon= \oint \vec{E}.d\vec{s}$, it is work per unit charge. It must have something to work against ? Do you mean $\epsilon$ works against the other EMF (the one from the current or voltage generator supplying the solenoid the current $I(t)$) ?

Yes, $\epsilon$ tells you how much work has to be done to push a charge through the coil. That induced emf is exactly what driving circuit is doing work against when it drives the solenoid. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question well enough to answer --- there are different ways to get mixed up on this topic and I'm not sure which one you are having trouble with.

Driving circuit works against induced emf. I think I got it (turned out to be easier for me to think in terms of work, instead of power)! Thanks!!
